# Unable to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. Could not calculate the upgrade. An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, 16.04

Unable to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. I'm trying `sudo do-release-upgrade` and it fails with the following error:

```
Calculating the changes

Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. 


Restoring original system state
```

/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gf1tg8uxmn75jq/main.log?dl=0
/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/79i2mf320pvg3bl/apt.log?dl=0

I don't understand why package manager can not resolve this and what package is the source of this problem.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the same problem using the 'About this computer' > 'Upgrade' route on a fully updated 14.04 LTS system.  I have software from quite a few alternative repositories, which several posts suggest might have caused the problem.

`grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` 
reported 163 lines, many of which were gnuplot related.  I note a few other posts that reported gnuplot as a problem.

I deleted the two gnuplot packages installed on my system using Synaptic and then closed Synaptic.  Interestingly, when filtering with 'installed(upgradeable)' in Synaptic, only these two packages showed up (gnuplot and gnuplotX11) and both had an exclamation mark in the checkbox.

Then `do-release-upgrade` worked.

Comment: Ty @Pholorian, but I don't use gnuplot and ```grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log``` returns 700+ rows.

Comment: in my case it was something mplayer2 related. Uninstalling it and the upgrade worked again.

Comment: Same for me.  Pholorian's `grep` mentioned a few gnuplot packages.  After I `apt-get remove`d them, `do-release-upgrade`'s errors vanished.

Answer (score 3):

[Ivo van der Wijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/193364/ivo-van-der-wijk) reported [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805175/unable-to-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-an-unres/968296#comment1255771_808523) that **removing mplayer2** solved this problem and allowed the upgrade to proceed. This solution also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

In my list, `xserver-xorg-video-*` is shown. To remove that, run:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-*
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in some package which is may differ from user to user, so there is no common solution that suits every specific case, but there is an algorithm which helped me:

1. Try run `sudo do-release-upgrade`
2. Check logs at `/var/log/dist-upgrade/`, try to find packages that may cause an error
3. Remove the packages found in step 2 and return to step 1

I removed several different packages and at some point release upgrade did run well

Answer (score 1):

I was upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 but I assume this comment is still applicable.

First I followed the instructions [here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-linux-16-04-to-18-04/). After running `sudo do-release-upgrade` I got the long "Unresolvable problem" error message.
I checked `grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` and many of the broken packages were from ros-kinetic. So I uninstall ros-kinetic

`sudo apt remove ros-kinetic-*`

and then ran the upgrade

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

After that the upgrade no longer threw that error