# Don't know how to remove packages to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, ppa, do-release-upgrade

I have been trying to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 for a few weeks with no success. As many others (e.g., [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805175/unable-to-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-an-unres)), I get an error message saying that Ubuntu "could not calculate the upgrade". I tried to inspect `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` to find out what packages were causing the issue, and got a list of approximately [800 broken packages](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/277979930/VarLogDistupgradeAptlog.txt):

```
Broken dpkg:amd64 Breaks on libapache2-mod-php5 [ amd64 ] < 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.19 > ( httpd ) (< 5.6.4+dfsg-3~)
Broken perl-base:amd64 Breaks on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 > ( perl ) (< 5.22.1~)
Broken findutils:amd64 Breaks on libpython3.4-minimal [ amd64 ] < 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.4 > ( python ) (< 3.4.4-2)
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libnettle4 [ amd64 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken libgnutls30:amd64 Conflicts on libnettle4 [ i386 ] < 2.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs )
Broken systemd:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-services [ amd64 ] < 204-5ubuntu20.19 > ( admin )
Broken systemd:amd64 Conflicts on systemd-services [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken texlive-binaries:amd64 Breaks on luatex [ amd64 ] < 0.76.0-3ubuntu1 > ( tex ) (< 2014)
Broken libopencv-core2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-core2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Breaks on libgnome-control-center1 [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( libs )
Broken xserver-xorg-core:amd64 Conflicts on xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl [ amd64 ] < 0.6.0+git1603170630.347ef4~gd~t > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-core:amd64 Conflicts on xserver-xorg-video-modesetting [ amd64 ] < 0.8.1-1build1 > ( x11 )
Broken unity-control-center-faces:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-control-center-shared-data [ amd64 ] < 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu56.1 > ( gnome )
Broken libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth:amd64 Conflicts on account-plugin-windows-live [ amd64 ] < 0.11+14.04.20140409.1-0ubuntu2 > ( gnome )
Broken ghc-doc:amd64 Breaks on libghc-transformers-doc [ amd64 ] < 0.3.0.0-5 > ( doc ) (< 0.3.0.0-6)
Broken libasprintf0v5:amd64 Breaks on libasprintf0c2 [ amd64 ] < 0.18.3.1-1ubuntu3 > ( libs )
Broken libopencv-imgproc2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-imgproc2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )
```

The list goes on forever, but it might already give an idea of what is going on. Anyway, I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1611430) on the Ubuntu tracker, and was told that the problem was probably that I installed PPA packages that were incompatible with the new version. They suggested that I remove those packages with `ppa-purge`, specifically from the `oibaf` PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge oibaf
```

However, I then get an error:

```
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: oibaf ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: oibaf ppa
```

Any clue on how this issue could be solved?

Comment: First of all, ppa-purge doesn't work like that. You need to use the same name of the PPA when you add it. In this case "ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers". Secondly, and after reverting the changes made by that PPA, you should fully upgrade within the current version by using "dist-upgrade".

Comment: Better backup and install from scratch. Honestly, you're wasting a lot of time with something that has a simple, better and safer solution.

Comment: @CelticWarrior "sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers" yields pretty much the same error message: "Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: oibaf graphics-drivers".

Comment: Try sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/ppa. It should work.

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam No, it does not.

Comment: There no space after the  ":". Other than that my suggestion (in the second comment) stands.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Sorry, what ":" exactly are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about the difference between "ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers¨ (correct) and "PPA: oibaf graphics-drivers" (incorrect) or "ppa: oibaf graphics-drivers" (incorrect). The point, again, is to use the exact same name you used when adding it with apt-add-repository. It doesn't work any other way and certainly not with "ppa-purge oibaf" that you mention in the question. Again, second comment. I won't be wasting any more time with this.

Comment: @CelticWarrior It is a shame that you did not even bother to read my response: I typed exactly "ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers", and not"PPA: oibaf graphics-drivers" or anything else.

Comment: Did you try removing any other repository? Does it work then?

Comment: @EmadArshadAlam Thank you for your follow up. I do have a few other PPAs listed on `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, but I also think that I had already purged some of them earlier. In any case, I tried just now and there was one other PPA that I was able to remove: ppa:webupd8team/java. Is there any way to figure out which packages in the above broken list are related to which PPAs?

Comment: Do you mind pasting the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: Go to `Ubuntu Software Centre`, then in the menu  choose `Ubuntu Software`, click on `Software and Updates`.  Choose `Other Software` and uncheck all 3rd party repositories and then try.